# Getting "Segmentation fault: 11" with ogr in Python

Tags: python, ogr, osgeo

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
In [1]: from osgeo import ogr

In [2]: datasource = ogr.Open('testdata.shp')

In [3]: datasource.GetLayerCount()
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: layer = datasource.GetLayerByIndex(0)

In [5]: layer.GetName()
Segmentation fault: 11
```

It doesn't matter what datasource I use. I've tried with several (even different formats) but I keep getting the same result.

Anyone faced this issue before? I've tried reinstalling `gdal` (in my computer) and `GDAL` (Python bindings) but still no luck. The weirdest thing is that it was working fine 2 days ago, and suddently started failing.

- OS X v10.8.5
- GDAL==1.10.0

Comment: Can you upload your shapefile somewhere? I'd be happy to check it with working software to makes sure it's not corrupted data.